# $f(x)=x^3 - x^2 + (x-1)\sin x$. Let $g(x)$ be an arbitrary function. If $fg$ is differenciable at $x=1$, then is $g$ continuous at $x=1$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

The question is as such-

> $f(x)=x^3 - x^2 + (x-1)\sin x$. Let $g(x)$ be an arbitrary function. If $fg$ is differentiable at $x=1$, then is $g$ continuous at $x=1$?

Here is what I could figure out:

$f(x)$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(1)=0$.
There are 3 cases-

- *Case 1:*
  $g(x)$ is differentiable and continuous. Then their product will always be differentiable.
- *Case 2:*
  $g(x)$ is non differentiable but continuous, then their product will be continuous if and only if $f(1)=0$.
- *Case 3:*
  $g(x)$ is discontinuous and hence non-differentiable. Then, is it possible for $fg$ to be differentiable?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Simple example: $g(x)=0$ for $x\ne1$ and $g(1)=1$.